# ¿Cómo puedo ingresar varios valores a una misma columna? Quisiera poder realizar una base de datos de una escuela

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una base de datos hecha en la cual, al realizar el login de los usuarios de la escuela, debo ingresar a cada alumno y eso está bien porque en ese caso es agregar el curso del alumno y ya está pero, en caso de los preceptores debo poner más de un curso y en caso del directivo debe tener acceso a todos los cursos y en mi caso de administrador también, por lo que quería saber cómo podría hacer para agregar varios valores a un usuario y en una misma columna.

Answer (score 0):

Eso lo puedes hacer con relaciones de tablas, que para el ejemplo actual seria una relacion de mucho a mucho.

Por Ejemplo, tener las siguientes tablas:

```
Usuarios{
 id, nombre, etc
}

Cursos{
 id, nombrecurso, etc
}
```

En esta tabla se expone la relacion mucho a mucho entre ambas tablas
Lo puedes hacer en base a roles en vez de usuarios, y que los usuario tengan relacion con los roles.

```
RelUsuarioCurso {
 id, usuarioId, cursoId 
}
```

Comment: Me olvidé de aclarar que las relaciones las hice, entre la columna "rol_id" con la tabla "roles columna=idrol", la columna "materias_id" con la tabla "materias columna=idmaterias" y la columna "curso_id" con la tabla "curso columna=idcurso", pero necesito poner, por ejemplo *El usuario con ID 2 debe contener en la columna "curso_id" los numeros "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, y 6" que describen a sus respectivos años, por eso quería saber si de alguna forma puedo agregar varios valores a una fila y en una sola columna, no sé si se entiende

Comment: Ezequiel, analiza bien la respuesta que te han dado, lo que necesitas  es una table que relacione los usuario con los cursos, tu mencionas que necesitas que el Usuario con ID 2 Tenga más de un Curso, eso exactamente es lo que logras con una tabla nueva en la que vas a tner el ID de Usuario 2 con el ID del curso, en esa tabla tendrás las veces que necesites al usuario con diferentes ID de curso uno por cada registro, luego para consultar solo realizas un join a esa tabla donde el usuarioId sea igual al usuario y ya obtendrás todos los cursos que corresponden al usuario, esa es la forma correcta

Comment: @omargt8 No dejen información sensible en los comentarios, están dando de comer a los bots para que puedan spamear :)

Comment: Lo mismo para @EzequielGuzmán.

Comment: Ok @padaleiana, ya quité la información, saludos